# How to feed a "params" function "params" of another function unfoldedly

Tags: c#, function, parameters

Two functions in c#

```
void foo1(params System.Object[] list){

}

void foo2(params System.Object[] list){

}
```

I want to unfold the "list" in one function and send it to the other function.
by unfold I mean to turn the list into 
    int var1, string var2, int var3, , , 
ofcoarse with knowing dynamically what the types of each argument is.

In case you are asking why? would you do that? its because I am implementing a generic Network utility on top of Unity3D Networking environment and the two functions are actually on different computers, while the Unity3d networking environment imposes that only basic types be sent, like "string", "Vector3", "double" and such, so passing one list to the other doesn't pass.

Comment: What do you mean by "unfold" ?

Answer (score 2):

Just call `foo2` with the list.

```
foo2(list);
```

The compiler will now pass the array as the params array (in contrast to creating a one-element array).

If you first want to calculate the argument somehow, make sure it is typed as `object[]` before passing it to `foo2`. Probably, you have to document what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `params AnyType[] argumentName`, C# allows you to call it in two ways:

- passing a variable number of arguments

  ```
  foo2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  ```
- passing an array of the expected type

  ```
  foo2(new object[] { arg1, arg2, arg3 })
  ```

That means that you can pass the received argument, from one funcion to another without problems... or if you want to change the array somehow, you could use linq, for example, and convert the final result using `.Cast<object>().ToArray()`:

```
void foo1(params System.Object[] list)
{
    foo2(list.Where(... condition )
        .Select(... select something)
        .Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Or you could append items to the list, passing more arguments to `foo2`:

```
void foo1(params System.Object[] list)
{
    foo2(list.Concat(new [] { "another-param" }).Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Or prepend:

```
void foo1(params System.Object[] list)
{
    foo2((new object[] { "another-param" }).Concat(list).Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: hmm linq, maybe, I am asking this because I need a way to unfold the parameter list because Unity3D Networking allows only specific types to be sent. and Object[] is not one of them.

how does linq work will it turn the list into the regular comma seperated parameters?

Comment: Are you trying to pass aditional parameters along with the ones received by `foo1` to `foo2`... if this is what you are trying to accomplish, then see my edit.

Comment: no the problem is that foo2() is not my function, it doesn't want to recieve anything except "string", "Vector3", "double", the basics.

the list is actually made of those simple types. So theoretically its possible to unfold the first list and send it to the second list as comma seperated variables. But I dont think that c# is dynamic enogh for it. 

What I will probably have to do is loop through all the possible variations of the function call.

Comment: Then you can just pass the received array to `foo2`... no need to unfold it. Look at the start of the answer... those two statements are equivalent, they are compiled by C# in the same way.

Comment: hmm didn't work, well its too late now anyways, I got deadlines so I had to remake the entire design of the communication. (C style always wins in the end)